# App Engine: Redirecting domain (not google apps) to appengine without Host records

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform, cname-record, g-suite, google-app-engine

I would like to redirect a domain to app engine, but my Domain provider only allows me to set information for Primary DNS and Secondary DNS. It means that there is no possibilities to set host records (cname, A, etc)

I think I do have to use a DNS Provider, but I'd like to know your opinion on what's the best way to do it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to find a proper DNS provider. Period. End of story.

There is no way of doing anything productive with your domain without DNS records.

Comment: yes, right! do you recommend DynDNS or another else?